# PK Field Does Not Allow Pivot to Display as 1 Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to Pivot a table and display the results in 1 record. This all works if there is no PK field , but there is one and I am not getting the desired result. You can use the statement below to Test.

```
Create table #Test
(id int identity(1,1), item_name varchar(50),item_value varchar(50), decode float )

insert into #Test (item_name, item_value, decode)
values ('Threshold', 'GROWTH', 0.6),
        ('Threshold', 'LEVERAGE', 0.4)

Select pvt.* from #Test d
Pivot (
    max(d.decode)
    for d.item_value in (Growth,Leverage)
) as pvt
where item_name = 'Threshold'

drop table #test
```

The Results of this Query are

```
 | id | item_name | Growth | Leverage

    1   Threshold    0.6      NULL 
    2   Threshold    NULL     0.4
```

My Desired Results are

```
   item_name  | Growth | Leverage 

   Threshold     0.6       0.4
```

If you remove the Identity column from the create statement I can achieve the result I am looking for, but I can't do this because I am using real tables. How can I make the query 'bypass' the id column and achieve my desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the PK is unique (an identity) for each row, you'll need to exclude it from the query or it will be including in the grouping aspect of PIVOT. To get around this, you'll want to use a subquery to select only the columns needed for the PIVOT.

Change your query to the follow:

```
Select item_name, Growth,Leverage
from
(
  select item_name, item_value, decode
  from #Test
  where item_name = 'Threshold'
) d
Pivot 
(
  max(d.decode)
  for d.item_value in (Growth,Leverage)
) as pvt;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/37602).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a crosstab for this instead of PIVOT.

```
select item_name
    ,MAX(case when item_value = 'Growth' then decode end) as Growth
    , MAX(case when item_value = 'Leverage' then decode end) as Leverage
from #Test
where item_name = 'Threshold'
group by item_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(Select d.*,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY 
  item_name ORDER BY item_name DESC )rn 
    from #Test d)

Select item_name,
       Growth,
       Leverage
  FROM 
  (select item_name, item_value, decode
    from CTE
  where item_name = 'Threshold'  )d
Pivot (
    max(d.decode)
    for d.item_value in (Growth,Leverage)
) as pvt
```